# SQL Server - Implicit transactions connections string

Tags: sql-server, transactions, implicit

I have Instance with 30 databases and I need to know in what databases the applications connections strings using implicit transactions.

There is a way to find it out?

Thanks

Comment: Simple, all of them. Implicit transactions are required to maintain ACID. https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/12/09/sql-server-acid-atomicity-consistency-isolation-durability/

Comment: Also you seem to be a little confused. A database does not have a connection string, those are in your application. So the whole basis of your question is rather flawed.

Comment: I run sp_blitzfirst and getting it, and in the internet the suggestion was to stop using implicit transactions. so I want to figure out who run queries with implicit transaction

Comment: You might need to read about what that means. Every database uses implicit transactions for DML operations when there is not an explicit transaction being used. This means that EVERY single insert, update, delete is using an implicit transaction unless you use an explicit transaction. Curious what not using implicit transactions would help anything. Can you share the link where you found this suggestion?

Comment: From this link I understood that implicit transactions are bed:  https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/05/implicit-vs-explicit-conversion/

Comment: Ummm....the link you posted is about implicit **conversion** but you are asking about **transactions**. I think you need to figure out what you are actually asking and try to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

There is a great deal of confusion in this space. Exactly what you you mean by "implicit transaction"? If you can answer that, then we might be able to take this further.

What I am trying to say is that some folks interpret that term in the sense than each DML command is implicitly a transactions. And of course it is!

But other folks interpret the term in the sense that "we turn off autocommit", which you do with the command SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON.

Confusing, huh? :-)

So, I guess that the question is: Can you connect with a connection string so that autocommit is turned off (the behaviour you get with SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTION ON). I'm pretty sure there isn't and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.columnencryptionsetting?view=netframework-4.7.2 doesn't list any such attribute.

Comment: What I meant about Implicit transactions that this is transactions with begin transaction without commit or rollback (this is what I understood). and I want to figure out what are the applications that doing it

Comment: OK, seems we have left the "implicit transaction" territory now. You want to find out session which has started a transaction but not committed the transaction. There certainly isn't anything in the connection string about this (you referred to the connection string in your first post). Starting a transaction is something you do, by executing some command. And the question here is: how would you separate a "normal" started transaction that will commit at some point in time from a rouge transaction which is out of control? Both are open...